# Solr returns same result after adding document with SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am trying to get the results from a Solr query, doing a simple /select?q=id:xx
The problem is that its not returning anything when i use solr directly, but when i use SolrJ, like:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(queryStr);
query.setRows(10);
QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.getSolrServer().query(query);
```

It returns the document added with no problem.
How is that possible, i was thinking perhaps the SolrJ its sending an extra parameter internally but i couldnt find it.

I am using Solr 4.2.1

Comment: SolrJ uses `wt=javabin` extra param, but I don't see why that would return results when the direct query doesn't. Try querying Solr directly with `wt=xml` or `wt=json` and see if you get any results.

Comment: thats not helping, i was already sending this extra params: &wt=xml&indent=true.

Maybe its something related with cache? but what its strange its that from SorlJ im getting th updated info.

Comment: How do you add data to the index? Probably it has something to do with commit, resp. the not-commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some test i solved the problem, i had to use HttpSolrServer, instead of EmbeddedSolrServer, it seems EmbeddedSolrServer use their own data somehow, so i was managing 2 different datas.
Using HttpSolrServer was the solution.